# WooCommerce Custom fields: Customizing jQuery Datepicker Plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using WooCommerce with a plugin that provides custom fields on a product page. One of the options is a date picker. Although, the product sold is only available on specific days of the week (e.g. Monday and Wednesday).

I understand how to get this effect, and an extensive google search gave me heaps of options. But I really don't understand where to put it, and how to override the plugin files.

The plugin I'm using is "WooCommerce Custom Fields & Product Add-ons", found at: http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-fields-product-addons/11332742?s_rank=3. I have messaged the author for help but they just said their support doesn't cover customisation.

How do I edit the plugin's jQuery files to have specific days selectable in the date picker? 
Where would I find the files to achieve this effect?

I have found this section of code over at another question on stack overflow regarding the date picker ([Disable specific days of the week on jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968414/disable-specific-days-of-the-week-on-jquery-ui-datepicker)):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 1 && day != 2)];
    }
})​​​​​;​
```

I am just unsure where to go from here.

I have been searching forever and decided to ask the community.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You have to give us the code on how you added the custom fields.

Comment: Are you using **Advance custom fields** plugin? If yes update your question with that details… [See this related thread about Advance Custom Fields and ACF date-picker plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37982789/3730754). Please update your question with more details, including the plugins you are using with their links and any interesting reference you have found. If you have some code, add it explaining what is working and what not…